# Cannot getText From Alert Dialog Android

Tags: android, gettext

i have trouble in getText from EditText, i have make all the method that i know but it doesn't work Eventhough i filled the editText the answer allways says Field is required. Here is my code

```
 private void buildDialog(int animationSource) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_activation, null);
    builder.setView(mView);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = animationSource;
    dialog.show();

    Button mLogin = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnAktivasi);
    mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AllowingToUpdate();
        }
    });
}

private void AllowingToUpdate() {
    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_activation, null);

    //I want to get Text From mMesin
    EditText mMesin = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.etMesin);
    String NoMesin = mMesin.getText().toString();

    //Toast display always "Field is required" eventhough i have filled the editText

    if(mMesin.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Field Is Required....",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"This Is Work....."+NoMesin,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What “trouble”?

Comment: Always Display Toast "Field is Required" eventhough i have filled the edit text

Comment: Pass your mView to the AllowingToUpdate() method as parameter  as allowingToUpdate(mView) and from that view access the edit text. That will solve your problem

Comment: Yes you're right the solution is just pass mView as parameter and it works...Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inflating the layout again which will give you a new layout(View) which does not attached to `AlertDialog`.
Keep the things Simple and use the same view which is added to `AlertDialog`. See the code below you will get the idea .

```
 private void buildDialog(int animationSource) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_activation, null);
    builder.setView(mView);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = animationSource;
    dialog.show();
    final EditText mMesin = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.etMesin);
    Button mLogin = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnAktivasi);
    mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mMesin.getText().toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, "Field Is Required....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, "This Is Work....." + mMesin.getText().toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Or** you can pass `mView` as a parameter to method `AllowingToUpdate`. This will also solve it .

Comment: I also pass mView as a parameter and it also works...once again thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Change your buildDialog method with below:

Make your **String NoMesin** global.

```
private void buildDialog(int animationSource) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    builder.setView(mView);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = animationSource;
    dialog.show();

    final EditText mMesin = mView.findViewById(R.id.etMesin);

    mMesin.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            NoMesin = mMesin.getText().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            NoMesin = mMesin.getText().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            NoMesin = mMesin.getText().toString();
        }
    });

    //Toast display always "Field is required" eventhough i have filled the editText

    Button mLogin = mView.findViewById(R.id.btnAktivasi);
    mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(NoMesin)) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Field Is Required....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This Is Work....." + NoMesin, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @ImmanuelSaragih updated my answer which will surely work for you.

Comment: I have made it but the result still same